# Use term-by-term differentiation to solve for Fourier Cosine Series of even periodic extension of $e^x$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

An even periodic extension of $e^x$ will be represented by the following Fourier Cosine Series:

\begin{align*}
  e^x &\sim A_0 + \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty A_n \cos \frac{n \pi x}{L} \\
\end{align*}

The easy way to solve for the coefficients is to use simple trigonometric orthogonality properties:

\begin{align*}
  A_0 &= \frac{1}{L} \int_0^L e^x \, dx = \frac{e^L-1}{L} \\
  A_n &= \frac{2}{L} \int_0^L e^x \cos \frac{n \pi x}{L} \, dx \\
\end{align*}

However, for this textbook problem I am explicitly supposed to use term-by-term differentiation approach to solve this.

Term by Term Differentiation yields:

\begin{align*}
  e^x &\sim - \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n \pi}{L} A_n \sin \frac{n \pi x}{L} \\
\end{align*}

My work:

Over the interval of $[0,L]$, these two representations of $e^x$ will be identical:

\begin{align*}
  A_0 + \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty A_n \cos \frac{n \pi x}{L} &= - \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n \pi}{L} A_n \sin \frac{n \pi x}{L} \\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  A_0 + \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty A_n \left( \frac{n \pi}{L} \sin \frac{n \pi x}{L} + \cos \frac{n \pi x}{L} \right) &= 0 \\
\end{align*}

I'm really stumped on what to do from here.

Comment: When the derivative is $L^2_{loc}$ it coincides with the termwise differentiation of the Fourier series. Here the derivative is odd : how to you compute its Fourier coefficients, that's where you'll use $(e^x)'=e^x$

Comment: What is $L^2_{loc}$? Obviously, the cosine series is even, and the derivative of that will be odd, and the equality will only apply over $[0,L]$. I don't follow your hint on how to approach this problem.